# Database in a Xamarin mobile client which uses the Azure Mobile App service

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm building a Xamarin mobile app, which offline-syncs using Azure Mobile App service.

A. Xamarin (mobile client):
Xamarin's docs show how to build an app and a local database (using the `sqlite-net` ORM). Models are annotated with various attributes.

B. Azure Mobile App service (server):
Azure's docs show how to define models in the mobile app (without sqlite-net), and define similar models on the server app (using a customised Entity Framework). The client models use different attributes, and the server models don't use any attributes and derive from `EntityData`.

But then the client has two databases - the "real" one (A), and the one from the Azure APIs (B).

**Am I supposed to only implement (B)?**

Which means, (A) is only if I want a local database, and I don't need the `sqlite-net` ORM at all?

Comment: are you using this feature ? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-offline-data/

Comment: @Aravind yes that is part of the docs I was referring to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/), then you shouldn't do A, since the local database is already created for you as part of the offline sync feature. You do B as part of the C# ASP.NET server programming model, or you can use Easy Tables with a Node.js backend.

If you don't want a cloud connected app at all and the data to be stored only locally (i.e., no offline sync with a service), then do A only.

Alternatively, if you want the ORM provided by `sqlite-net` (rather than just basic querying and CRUD in the Azure Mobile client SDK), you can define a custom local store based on `sqlite-net`. To do this, create an implementation of [IMobileServiceLocalStore](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Table/Sync/IMobileServiceLocalStore.cs). The Mobile Apps client SDK is open source, so you can use  [MobileServiceSQLiteStore](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore/MobileServiceSQLiteStore.cs) as a starting point.

Comment: Wow, knowledge straight from the source, thanks! :-)

Comment: That `sqlite-net` library is a basic but functional ORM. The offline-sync APIs are even more basic than that, and not really an ORM (from what I can see?) Could one use both at the same time, so that I get ORM functionality on the client? (On the server I get that automatically, as it appears the APIs are based on EF.)

Comment: @hbob Yes, but you would have to write your own implementation of IMobileServiceLocalStore based on the sql-net library. The SDK is open source. And yes, the SDK is provides only basic object mapping.